# how to stop a form going to the next page without giving values

Tags: html, forms, submit

i have created a form.But when i click on the submit button without giving values, it goes to the next page. i only want it happen after giving values.

```html
<form action="form" method="post" style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter your user name "><br>
     <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password "><br>


  <form action="form" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</form >
<form method="get" action="register" style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;">
   <button type="submit" >Register</button>
</form>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `id` attribute to your form element and attach a `submit` event listener to it like below.

```
document.getElementById("userForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  // prevent the form from submitting
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // get the form input values
  var _username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var _password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  
  // check if the input fields are empty
  if (_username === "" || _password === "") {
    alert("Please fill in all fields");
  } else {
    // allow the form to submit
    this.submit();
  }
});
```

Your html should be like below

```
<form action="form" id="userForm" method="post" style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="enter your user name "><br>
     <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password "><br>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i did as you said. But not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add `required` attribute to your input which are required to submit a form.

for Example
`<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter your user name" required>`

after adding required here user have to fill this input field to submit a form, without filling it user cannot submit a form.

Hope this will help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add required property in input field..
I have added in some input.

```html
<form action="form" method="post" style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter your user name " required><br>
     <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password " required><br>


  <form action="form" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</form >
<form method="get" action="register" style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;">
   <button type="submit" >Register</button>
</form>
```